# php regex combine repeated list with single occurrence and exclude whole words

Tags: php, regex, regex-negation

I fail with some regex task I need for replacing some text information.

The following task can be done also in not regex but if would be nice to have it in regex because there is much to replace.

However the question is:

- find characters in the set `[\w\. \&\=\?\-\(\)\'\+]` which can be occure 3-99 times, so write: `[\w\. \&\=\?\-\(\)\'\+]{3-99}`
- Within the list a newline *can* appear *once*, so write `\n?`
- after this characters a fixed string appears, so just write: `<test@mail.se>`
- but within the list of characters the word "for" should not appear

So if I use: `((?!for)[\w\. \&\=\?\-\(\)\'\+]{3,99}|(\n?))<test@mail\.se>` the word 'for' will be matched even though. Do anyone has an idea?

So example:
Within this string:

```
    To: Lasse Erikson <test@mail.se>
```

I want to match the name and the mail.

Even here:

```
To: Lasse Erikson <test@mail.se>, Sara
    Larsson <mail@mail.se>
```

But here I want not fetch anything:

```
 for <test@mail.se>; Thu, 14 Dec 2017 21:18:22 +0100 (CET)
```

Because there is a "for" in the line.

I hope you understand this...

Thank you in advance

Comment: So basically you want to match name and email in `To:` field?

Comment: Yes somehow, but there are also other fields, so I just want to turn it around and exclude fields with 'for' as value. I know I can work around this with `strpos` and some other php code, but if there is a way in regex I like to prefer it...

Comment: could you post a bigger input data example (with all those fields)?

Comment: Check if this is what you are expecting https://regex101.com/r/5fgPxb/2/tests

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP (PCRE) provides some verbs to skip over or fail current matching process that you can use to skip over word `for` or fail whole match if you want:

```
((?(?=\bfor\b)for(*SKIP)(*F))[ \w.(&=?\-+)](?(2)|(\R)?)){3,99}<[^<>@]*@[^<>]*>
```

[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/bo34et/1)

Breakdown:

```
(   # Start of capturing group #1
    (?(?=\bfor\b)for(*SKIP)(*F))    # Skip over `for` if any
    [ \w.(&=?\-+)]  # Match whitelist characters
    (?(2)|(\R)?)    # One newline character between
){3,99} # Between 3 or 99 times, end of CG #1
<[^<>@]*@[^<>]*> # Match an email format
```

Comment: the difference between `(*SKIP)` and `(*PRUNE)` is that after failure with `(*SKIP)` is that the input string cursor for next match keep the position at `(*FAIL)` (or `(*F)` or `(?!)`) maybe you mean `(?=\bfor\b)[^>]*(*SKIP)(*F)`

Comment: @NahuelFouilleul I didn't talk about `(*PRUNE)` anywhere but no I didn't mean to skip over email too since I thought about `for Lasse Erikson <test@mail.se>` as well. But it completely depends on OP.

Comment: wow thank you two @revo and Nahuel Fouilleul this saved my day ;)